# mysql error to run chapter 1 of getting started with chef

Tags: mysql, chef-infra

I am following the chapter 1 of tutorial http://gettingstartedwithchef.com/ and downloaded all dependencies listed in chapter1. The command "chef-solo -c solo.rb -j web.json" should be working, but I got the following error.

I googled the error that is shown as below and found that someone suggested to run a resource before any others (like to configure a package manager, apt/yum/etc). But how to do this? All links redirected to chef homepage...

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
yum_package[mysql] action install
 * No candidate version available for mysql
================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'yum_package[mysql]'
================================================================================

Chef::Exceptions::Package
-------------------------
No candidate version available for mysql

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /root/chef-repo/cookbooks/mysql/recipes/client.rb

 47:   package name
 48: end

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /root/chef-repo/cookbooks/mysql/recipes/client.rb:47:in `block in from_file'

yum_package("mysql") do
  action :install
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  default_guard_interpreter :default
  package_name "mysql"
  timeout 900
  flush_cache {:before=>false, :after=>false}
  declared_type :package
  cookbook_name :mysql
  recipe_name "client"
end
```

Running handlers:

```
[2015-05-15T10:28:13-04:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2015-05-15T10:28:13-04:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2015-05-15T10:28:13-04:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /root/chef-solo/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 4.248307605 seconds
[2015-05-15T10:28:13-04:00] ERROR: yum_package[mysql] (mysql::client line 47) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Package: No candidate version available for mysql
[2015-05-15T10:28:13-04:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is distributed via the '[mysql-server](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/mysql-server)' and '[mysql-client](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/mysql-client)' packages.

You can use one of those to satisfy your dependency.

```
yum_package("mysql-server") do
...
package_name "mysql-server"
```

or

```
yum_package("mysql-client") do
...
package_name "mysql-client"
```

Those packages are wrappers that (currently) point to 'mysql-server-5.6' and 'mysql-client-5.6' respectively. If you need a different version (for example: [mysql-client-5.1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mysql-client-5.1)), you can specify it instead.

```
yum_package("mysql-client-5.1") do
...
package_name "mysql-client-5.1"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, George. I figured out that the error was because my yum was not set up.